# OpenSSL CommandLine Windows Fully Updated

Tags: windows, openssl

```
openssl enc -e -bf -in X:\a.jpg -out X:\a -kfile Y:\password.txt
```

or

```
openssl enc -e -bf -in X:\a.jpg -out X:\a -k password
```

I get:

`###` is some number always different

`###`:error20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.C:400:

It would seem it does not like writing to Drives. It use too work till I updated even then it was sort of iffy.

I have tried every Windows admin rights I think of http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-with-administrator-privileges-in-windows-vista/